# How to select and copy a group of polygons in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, select

I'm new to QGIS. I opened a few shapefiles that cover Europe. Now I want to select a smaller area and if possible copy the polygons in this area so I can work with a smaller set. How should I do this in QGIS?

I started to choose "toogle to editing", then I choosed the  "node tool" and started to make rectangle. But then I get a popup (see screenshot below) telling me to set a "tolerance".

I looked in (as suggested in the popup) "Settings" > "Project properties" > "General", but couldn't find and any tolerance value here.

From the User Guide (version 1.7.0) in chapter 4.5.1 it was suggested that I should change the tolerance in "Settings" > "Options" > "Digitizing" and I changed from 0.00000 to 1.00000. It was also suggested to edit "Settings" > "Snapping options" so I changed the tolerance to the same value there.

Now I tried with the "Node tool" again, but I got the same popup and couldn't select any polygons.

How can I select an area of polygons in QGIS? that I later can copy to a new project in QGIS to get a smaller set to work with.

[image]

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Guk9b.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Guk9b.png) this is the problem the qgis can not selet a group of buildings...........

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The select tool has a "Select by Rectangle" option. (There are also freehand/polygon options if that would be more appropriate.)

[image]

*The node tool is for digitizing. I don't think that's what you want to do here.*

Then, right-click on the layer in layer list and use "Save selection as ...". This will create a new file with the features you selected. (You can chose from many different formats.) Afterwards, load the file into the same old or a new project.